# Split wav file into byte arrays with NAudio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, naudio

I would like to know how can I split the channels of a WAV file into two byte arrays with the PCM data.

I've been trying to do this with NAudio, but I can't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following to split wav file into two byte arrays.

```
 using (WaveFileReader pcm = new WaveFileReader(@"E:\\test.wav"))
            {
                int samplesDesired = 5000;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[samplesDesired * 4];
                short[] left = new short[samplesDesired];
                short[] right = new short[samplesDesired];
                int bytesRead = pcm.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                int index = 0;
                for (int sample = 0; sample < bytesRead / 4; sample++)
                {
                    left[sample] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, index);
                    index += 2;
                    right[sample] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, index);
                    index += 2;
                }
      
                MessageBox.Show("success");
            }
```